# bookmark modal window so next time it opens if the page is open

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

Using Bootstrap.

I have a lot of links on the page. 
Clicking on any of those links bringing up a modal window.

The Question:

I would like to be able to bookmark modal window so next time I use bookmark the specific modal window appears.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use url fragments http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you could use a hashtag in your url e.g. www.website.com/foo#modal1 and make a script which displays the modal depending on that hashtag.

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on("ready", function(){

    if(window.location.hash == '#modal1')
    {
        $("#modal1").modal('show');
    }
    $(".open-modal").click(function(){
        $("#modal1").modal('show');
        window.location.hash = 'modal1';
    });

    $(".close-modal").click(function(){
        $("#modal1").modal('hide');
        window.location.hash = '';
    });

});
```

**Html:**

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal hide fade">
Modal
<button class="close-modal">Close modal</button>
</div>

<button class="open-modal">Open modal</button>
```

Comment: any examples of using this?

Comment: works great for 2-3 modals. What if I have 30 modal windows on the page?

Comment: you can generalize this with a function which takes the hash (if it exists) for argument and shows the corresponding modal